# Chocolatey Installation of Visual Studio Pro 2012 is failing

Tags: visual-studio-2012, chocolatey, boxstarter

I'm using [Chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org) to install Visual Studio 2012 Professional

```
> cinst visualstudio2012professional
```

In my Chocolatey logs, I'm seeing that the install succeeded.

```
[DEBUG] Running 'Delete-ExistingErrorLog' for VisualStudio2012Professional
[DEBUG] Looking for failure log at 'C:\Users\Chase\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\VisualStudio2012Professional\failure.log'
[DEBUG] Found the failure log. Deleting it...
[DEBUG] Running 'Run-ChocolateyPS1' for VisualStudio2012Professional with packageFolder:'C:\chocolatey\lib\VisualStudio2012Professional.11.0.1', action: 'install'
[DEBUG]   __ PowerShell install (chocolateyinstall.ps1) __
[DEBUG]   Looking for chocolateyinstall.ps1 in folder 'C:\chocolatey\lib\VisualStudio2012Professional.11.0.1'. If chocolateyinstall.ps1 is found, it will be run.
[DEBUG] Action file is 'ChocolateyInstall.ps1'
[DEBUG] Running 'C:\chocolatey\lib\VisualStudio2012Professional.11.0.1\Tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'
[DEBUG] Running 'Install-ChocolateyPackage' for VisualStudio2012Professional with url:'http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9810233', args: '/Passive /NoRestart /AdminFile C:\chocolatey\lib\VisualStudio2012Professional.11.0.1\Tools\AdminDeployment.xml /Log C:\Users\Chase\AppData\Local\Temp\vs.log' 
[DEBUG] Running 'Get-ChocolateyWebFile' for VisualStudio2012Professional with url:'http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9810233', fileFullPath:'C:\Users\Chase\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\VisualStudio2012Professional\VisualStudio2012ProfessionalInstall.exe',and url64bit:'http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9810233'
[DEBUG] Processor width is 64.
Downloading VisualStudio2012Professional (http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9810233) to C:\Users\Chase\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\VisualStudio2012Professional\VisualStudio2012ProfessionalInstall.exe
[DEBUG] Running 'Get-WebFile' for C:\Users\Chase\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\VisualStudio2012Professional\VisualStudio2012ProfessionalInstall.exe with url:'http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9810233', userAgent: 'chocolatey command line' 
[DEBUG] Setting the UserAgent to 'chocolatey command line'
[DEBUG] Running 'Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage' for VisualStudio2012Professional with file:'C:\Users\Chase\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\VisualStudio2012Professional\VisualStudio2012ProfessionalInstall.exe', args: '/Passive /NoRestart /AdminFile C:\chocolatey\lib\VisualStudio2012Professional.11.0.1\Tools\AdminDeployment.xml /Log C:\Users\Chase\AppData\Local\Temp\vs.log' 
Installing VisualStudio2012Professional...
[DEBUG] Running 'Start-ChocolateyProcessAsAdmin' with exeToRun:'C:\Users\Chase\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\VisualStudio2012Professional\VisualStudio2012ProfessionalInstall.exe', statements: '/Passive /NoRestart /AdminFile C:\chocolatey\lib\VisualStudio2012Professional.11.0.1\Tools\AdminDeployment.xml /Log C:\Users\Chase\AppData\Local\Temp\vs.log ' 
Elevating Permissions and running C:\Users\Chase\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\VisualStudio2012Professional\VisualStudio2012ProfessionalInstall.exe /Passive /NoRestart /AdminFile C:\chocolatey\lib\VisualStudio2012Professional.11.0.1\Tools\AdminDeployment.xml /Log C:\Users\Chase\AppData\Local\Temp\vs.log . This may take awhile, depending on the statements.
[DEBUG] Finishing 'Start-ChocolateyProcessAsAdmin'
VisualStudio2012Professional has been installed.
VisualStudio2012Professional has finished succesfully! The chocolatey gods have answered your request!
[DEBUG] Running 'Get-ChocolateyBins' for C:\chocolatey\lib\VisualStudio2012Professional.11.0.1
[DEBUG]   __ Executable Links (*.exe) __
[DEBUG] Looking for executables in folder: C:\chocolatey\lib\VisualStudio2012Professional.11.0.1
Adding batch files for any executables found to a location on PATH. In other words the executable will be available from ANY command line/powershell prompt.
[DEBUG] There are no executables (that are not ignored) in the package.
[DEBUG] Evaluating NuGet output for line: 
Finished installing 'visualstudio2012professional' and dependencies - if errors not shown in console, none detected. Check log for errors if unsure.
```

But unfortunately, Visual Studio isn't installed. The folders were created, but the IDE isn't there. (there is no DevEnv.exe)

[image: devenv.exe isn't on my machine]

Are there log files somewhere that are associated with the VS installer? Maybe an answer lies in there.

Comment: The chocolatey package tells the vs installer to save its log to $env:temp\vs.log. Take a look at that and there is likely an error burried inside of it.

Comment: here's the log you're referring to. http://pastebin.com/WRtg5m87

Comment: I'm having same problem. The trouble is that somehow the exe is being passed the /layout parameter: (but it's not included in the package so I'm not sure how): C:\2aac9080afc1ec44bf2d4b\vs_professional.exe, cmdline: '/Passive /NoRestart /AdminFile C:\Chocolatey\lib\VisualStudio2012Professional.11.0.1\Tools\AdminDeployment.xml /Log C:\Users\Chase\AppData\Local\Temp\vs.log  /layout

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I can't get the download that is used in that package to install, I am running a PS script so I am going to use this which seems to work:

```
    $testFolder = Join-Path "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}" "Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
$alreadyInstalled = (Test-Path $testFolder)
if (!$alreadyInstalled)
{
    Install-ChocolateyPackage 'VisualStudio2012Professional' 'exe' "/Full /Passive /NoRestart /Log $env:temp\vs.log" 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/E/8/DE8E42D8-7598-4F4E-93D4-BB011094E2F9/vs_professional.exe'
}
```